# Accessing (Model) ApplicationRecord's name inside the class definition itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have this model definition for `Products` inside a Rails application. I need to get the name `products` inside the custom `after_initialize` method. In the code below, I have written it explicitly. My question is there a way to get the name `products` programmatically inside the model definition class?

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

    has_one :photo, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo

    after_initialize :set_photos_parent

    def set_photos_parent
        self.photo.parent = "products" unless self.photo.nil ?
    end

end
```

Comment: `self.class.model_name.human` is how you get a class name in Rails but I think you're trying to do something strange.

Comment: I mean, why are you trying to change the `self.photo.parent` attribute from this class? That logic should be kept in the `Photo` class, surely?

Comment: `self.class.model_name.downcase.pluralize` is what you are looking for. But could you provide more information why would you need to do that?

Comment: Thanks @RichardPeck, I have managed to do what I want using `self.class.model_name.human.pluralize`. In my situation, Photos can belong to Products and some other entities. I use `CarrierWave` to store the photos. When I build the path there (where to store the images) I need to access the parent entity a photo belong to and get its name. I have failed to do that inside `Photo` so I pass the parent name from the parent (Product) into the child (Photo).

Comment: Also it is `has_one :photo`, not `has_one: photo` (same for all other methods in this file)

Comment: I don't use Carrierwave but have you not considered a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to store uploads? We use an `Asset` model which we are then able to delegate to an unlimited number of subclasses because we store the association as polymorphic. I can explain more in an answer if warranted.

Comment: @RichardPeck, I have used `polymorphic associations` in the past but not to store files. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that was an Internet based code beautifier I have used while writing the question that made those mistakes.

Comment: @W.M.: well, please correct them.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to access the name of the parent class inside the child (e.g. accessing `products` inside `photo` model)?

Comment: @W.M.: yes, if you're using a polymorphic association and your photo class has something like `belongs_to :photo_container, polymorphic: true`, then you just do `photo_container.class.name` to access the dynamic parent class.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.class_name.pluralize.downcase
```